# Alternative ways to track dropped packets and report output

Tags: networking, ifconfig, ethtool

Instead of tailing /var/log/messages or doing a continuous ping is there a way with ifconfig or ethtool to track dropped packets, collisions, or tx/rx errors in real time?

Comment: I would use wrieshark as a gui or via the command line and have it run in ring-mode.

Comment: If you just need metrics you can use collectd to monitor and periodically report back the interface's error/collision counters. That's for measuring from the actual host. If you want to monitor reachability from another host collectd can also do a continuous ping and report packet loss.

Comment: Can tcpdump be configured to do this? I can't install collectd but I do have tcp dump. I'd like to monitor the interface but only log things likes errors, collisions and dropped packets. The send that to stdout.